# php variable not being passed to mail() "to line" parameter

Tags: php, email, variables

long time listener, first time caller...

I have recently started working through O'Reilly's "Head First" books on PHP, and this is one of their exercises - the code may look familiar to some of you.

The goal of the lesson was to demonstrate how the "mail" function in php works, and to that end they gave the following code to use as an example (edited for brevity/context):

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$to = 'myemail@myemail.com';
$subject = 'Abduction report';
$message = "$name .  was abducted $when_it_happened  and was gone for $how_long . \n" .
"Number of aliens: $how_many \n" .
"Alien description $alien_description\n" . 
"What they did: $what_they_did \n" .
"Fang spotted: $fang_spotted \n" .
"Other comments: $other";
mail($to, $subject, $message, 'From:' . $email);
```

----------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------

Per request, here is the results of `phpinfo()`:

```
System: Linux infong 2.4 #1 SMP Thu Feb 14 13:02:49 CET 2013 i686 GNU/Linux

Build date: Apr 10 2013 13:38:50

Configure Command: '../configure' '­­program­suffix=5' '­­with­pear=/usr/lib/php5' '­­with­    config­file­path=/usr/lib/php5' '­­with­libxml­dir' '­­with­mysqli' '­­with­kerberos' '­­with­imap­ssl' '­­enable­soap' '­­with­xsl' '­­enable­mbstring=all' '­­with­curl' '­­with­mcrypt' '­­with­gd' '­­with­pdo­mysql' '­­with­freetype­dir' '­­with­libxml­dir' '­­with­mysql' '­­with­zlib' '­­enable­debug=no' '­­enable­safe­mode=no' '­­enable­discard­path=no' '­­with­png­dir' '­­enable­track­vars' '­­with­db' '­­with­gdbm' '­­enable­force­cgi­redirect' '­­enable­fastcgi' '­­with­ttf' '­­enable­ftp' '­­enable­dbase' '­­enable­memory­limit' '­­enable­calendar' '­­enable­wddx' '­­with­jpeg­dir=/usr/src/kundenserver/jpeg­6b' 'enable­bcmath' '­­enable­gd­imgstrttf' '­­enable­shmop' '­­enable­mhash' '­­with­mhash' '­­with­openssl' '­­enable­xslt' '­­with­xslt­sablot' '­­with­dom' '­­with­dom­xslt' '­­with­dom­exslt' '­­with­imap' '­­with­iconv' '­­with­bz2' '­­with­gettext' '­­enable­exif' '­­with­idn' '­­with­sqlite' '­­enable­sqlite­utf8' '­­enable­zip' '­­with­tidy' '­­enable­gd­native­ttf'

Server API: CGI/FastCGI

Virtual Directory Support: disabled

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/lib/php5

Loaded Configuration File: /usr/lib/php5/php.ini

Scan this dir for additional .ini files: (none)

additional .ini files parsed: (none)

PHP API: 20041225

PHP Extension: 20060613

Debug Build: no

Thread Safety: disabled

Zend Memory Manager: enabled

IPv6 Support: enabled

Registered PHP Streams: https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, data, http, ftp, zip

Registered Stream Socket Transports: tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls

Registered Strem Filters: zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed
```

Everything works as expected except that I would receive no emails after filling out and submitting the form.

After removing the $to variable from "mail()" and replacing it with a static string ('myemail@myemail.com') I did get a properly formatted email.

I also concatenated the  "$to" variable to the body of the message and it displayed correctly from within the email body.

So I am at a loss as to why it cannot be used in the mail's "to" line. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried putting `'From:'.$email` into a `$headers` variable: `$headers = 'From: '.$email; ... mail($to,$sub,$msg,$headers)`?
Your code seems to be correct, but that doesn't mean your server likes it. What type of server is this running on? I also want to double quote your $to email, just to rule that out.

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question, but have you considered using a good quality mailer class instead of PHP's terrible built-in `mail()` function? I recommend downloading [phpMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). They make life *so* much easier for writing even simple email programs in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies... DAWSON: I just tried your "nested variable" idea and got no change. I neglected to mention that I had already tried double quotes and that was unsuccessful as well. The server is part of a hosting package, and since this is my very first foray into server-side scripting and my first serious attempt at programming in general, I thought the best answer to your "server type" question would be to post the (first page) response to `phpinfo();` - see the results above. SPUDLEY: Thank you for the suggestion... it's certainly worth a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing, but it's best I own up to it before consuming other people's valuable time...

After going to the PHP doc site, running several Google searches, and having another set of eyes look at the original code, the problem was - without going into too much detail - fixed by adding an 'r'. It was a TYPO hidden in a long email address.

Thanks for your help, Dawson, but you never had a chance!